# How to convert strings with UTC-# at the end to a DateTimeField in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, field, strptime

I have a list of strings formatted as follows: `'2/24/2021 3:37:04 PM UTC-6'`

How would I convert this?

I have tried

```
datetime.strptime(my_date_object, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%s %p %Z')
```

but I get an error saying "unconverted data remains: -6"

Is this because of the UTC-6 at the end?

Comment: I get "ValueError: 's' is a bad directive in format %m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%s %p UTC%z'"

Comment: Ok seems like you need to split the string on 'UTC' and parse the offset separately. You can then set the tzinfo from a timedelta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach that @[MrFuppes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10197418/mrfuppes) mentioned in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67591799/how-to-convert-strings-with-utc-at-the-end-to-a-datetimefield-in-python/67592593#comment119472657_67591799) is the easiest way to do this.

> Ok seems like you need to split the string on 'UTC' and parse the offset separately. You can then set the tzinfo from a timedelta

```
input_string = '2/24/2021 3:37:04 PM UTC-6'

try:
    dtm_string, utc_offset = input_string.split("UTC", maxsplit=1)
except ValueError:
    # Couldn't split the string, so no "UTC" in the string
    print("Warning! No timezone!")
    
    dtm_string = input_string
    utc_offset = "0"


dtm_string = dtm_string.strip() # Remove leading/trailing whitespace '2/24/2021 3:37:04 PM'
utc_offset = int(utc_offset)    # Convert utc offset to integer -6

tzinfo = tzinfo = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=utc_offset))

result_datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(dtm_string, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p').replace(tzinfo=tzinfo)

print(result_datetime)
# prints 2021-02-24 15:37:04-06:00
```

---

Alternatively, you can avoid using `datetime.strptime` if you extract the relevant components pretty easily with regular expressions

```
rex = r"(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) (AM|PM) UTC(\+|-)(\d{1,2})"

input_string = '2/24/2021 3:37:04 PM UTC-6'

r = re.findall(rex, input_string)
# gives:  [('2', '24', '2021', '3', '37', '04', 'PM', '-', '6')]

mm = int(r[0][0])
dd = int(r[0][1])
yy = int(r[0][2])

hrs = int(r[0][3])
mins = int(r[0][4])
secs = int(r[0][5])

if r[0][6].upper() == "PM":
    hrs = hrs + 12

tzoffset = int(f"{r[0][7]}{r[0][8]}")

tzinfo = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=tzoffset))

result_datetime = datetime.datetime(yy, mm, dd, hrs, mins, secs, tzinfo=tzinfo)
print(result_datetime)
# prints 2021-02-24 15:37:04-06:00
```

The regular expression `(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4}) (\d{1,2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}) (AM|PM) UTC(\+|-)(\d{1,2})`
[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZNHoOi/1)

Explanation:

- `(\d{1,2})`: One or two digits. Surrounding parentheses indicate that this is a capturing group. A similar construct is used to get the month, date and hours, and UTC offset
- `\/`: A forward slash
- `(\d{4})`: Exactly four digits. Also a capturing group. A similar construct is used for minutes and seconds.
- `(AM|PM)`: Either "AM" or "PM"
- `UTC(\+|-)(\d{1,2})`: "UTC", followed by a plus or minus sign, followed by one or two digits.

Comment: Parsing the part before 'UTC' with strptime might be a bit more convenient than the regex; you can set the tzinfo with `replace` subsequently

Comment: I agree. I figured you'd write an answer with that approach because you mentioned it in a comment already. Just giving OP options :) @MrFuppes